# Auto fill question form

Tags: support, asking-questions

Is it possible to auto fill new question form using GET parameters ?

I tried with

```
/questions/ask?title=Foo
```

it fills title well.

How can do it with question and tags ?

Comment: there is form for that

Comment: Why would you wanna do that?

Comment: I`m trying to generate some url to fill form from outside of browser (because of no write API) and open it when user fills form in my app.

Comment: [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Hello+I+need+title+pre-filled&tags=support+asking+questions). body can't be prefilled.

Comment: @juergend thought I had corrected it.. but seems not - thanks!

Comment: @hsz: that sounds like a bad idea. Do the users of your application *know and understand* how SO/SE works? Will they confuse this with a general "fix-this-for-me" support form? I see a lot of bad questions resulting from this.

Answer (score 5):

First there is a form for that. But you can pre-fill the text with URL parameters.

For tags (e.g., [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)) and title:

```
 /questions/ask?title=Foo&tags=c%23+.net
```

For the text area as well:

```
 /questions/ask?title=Foo&tags=c%23+.net&question=thisisfortextarea
```

Comment: Ok, what about textarea's content ?

Comment: Unfortunate example with c++ as tag. Using multiple tags would require to add them with +

Comment: The `question=` portion for the text area isn't working. (Just by pasting in the example above). Is there an alternative to put text in the question body?